# HTTP Post request with XML

Tags: xml, api, http, post

I am trying to impliment a web service called **[Navlost.eu](http://www.navlost.eu/nwxs/doc/help)** and I am not sure how to execute. I am knowledgeable on XML, PHP and JS apart from HTML and CSS.

What the website recommends is the following:

> This web service can be accessed via HTTP by sending an appropriately formatted POST request to the address http://navlost.eu/aero/nwx. The body of the request should be an XML document containing a valid NWX request, as described below in the Specification section.

How does one come about this? In terms of files that need to be created? The RAW examples that were provided reminded me of SOAP...

Any insight is appreciated - thank you.

Comment: You may want to clarify your post.  Which technology are you trying to generate a request from, PHP, or JavaScript?  Do you know how to issue basic HTTP Requests, etc.

Comment: I am attempting to use PHP. Yes I have experience with requests especially when creating a PHP shopping cart using a local xml file.

What I can not get around my head is how the POST statement such as:

POST /aero/nwx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.navlost.eu
Content-Length: 233
Content-Type: application/xml
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

is written by itself without any braces etc. 
I am trying to identify what kind of language is used in the RAW HTTP data examples provided in navlost.eu/nwxs/help in order to implement such a web service.

Comment: The Raw HTTP example from the navlost site is just that--the raw HTTP protocol text as communicated from client to server.  Do you know how to create an XML string in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in PHP, but it looks like the basic idea for making an HTTP request would be something like this.

```
$requestXml = new DOMDocument()
    ... Create Xml Request Document ...
$rawXml = $requestXml.saveXML();
$request = new HttpRequest("http://www.navlost.eu/aero/nwx",HTTP_METH_POST);
$request.setContentType('application/xml');
$request.setBody($rawXml);
$response = $request.send();
$responseXml = new DOMDocument();
$responseXml.loadXML($response.getBody());
    ... Process XML Response ...
```

It's going to be up to you to figure out the navlost.eu API so that you send the right requst and get the right responses back based on what actions you want to take.

Comment: Thanks drz appreciated I will get back one I've figured something out :)

Comment: cant 1up with <15reps but still working around for the solution